# URL - InputStream.available() less than URLConnection.getContentLength() why?

Tags: java, url, io, inputstream

i read a image from URL, like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://link-to-image");
```

then i want to checksum its content, so i need InputStream.mark() method. but i got IOException with message "Resetting to invalid mark" when i call reset()

image size is 82.271KB, and there are something strange:

```
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
con.getContentLength(); // value is 84246, correct
InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
is.available(); // value is 73203, incorrect
```

i can invoke reset() successed use mark(84246 + 1), why InputStream return wrong value?

***PS: if InputStream from File, available() is right.***

Comment: "is.available(); // value is 73203, incorrect", Not really just read the javadocs its just an estimation of the possible content, not the real length. You should first check if mark is supported on that stream implementation. Streams have no length till they are closed, they can still grow if they have not been closed.

Comment: [The documentation for InputStream.available()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available--) is pretty clear about this.  Under no circumstances should you rely on it to return the total number of bytes which can be read.

Answer (score 0):

This is from java documentation:

```
public long getContentLengthLong()

Returns the value of the content-length header field as a long.
```

So if it is a file you don't have headers and they match but when you do a http connection other than the stream with data itself it carries lots of other information (headers) and that's why the numbers don't match.

Comment: so, meaning that i can't get a correct value through InputStram.avaliable method by http connection stream?